# Apply a series of values from one table to a series of rows in another

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Suppose I have table `@A` with a series of rows where there's a column with `NULL` values for those rows, and I have table `@B` with (potentially fewer, or more) rows with values, how can I apply `@B`'s values to `@A`'s rows to fill in the `NULL`s, without changing `@B`? (Without using a cursor, I mean; fairly trivial with a cursor.) `@A` and `@B` are both in-memory (table variables) and will have only a small number of rows, so we don't have to worry about big data sets.

E.g., if I have:

```
DECLARE @A TABLE
(
        x INT,
        y NVARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO @A (y) VALUES ('aaa'), ('bbb'), ('ccc')

DECLARE @B TABLE
(
        x INT
)
INSERT INTO @B (X) values (1), (2)
```

Now I have `@A`:

```
x           y
----------- -----------
NULL        aaa
NULL        bbb
NULL        ccc
```

and `@B`:

```
x
-----------
1
2
```

...and I want to update `@A` based on `@B` so it has:

```
x           y
----------- -----------
1           aaa
2           bbb
NULL        ccc
```

...ideally in that order (e.g., the lowest value in `@B` becomes the `x` for the lowest `y` in `@A`, then the next, etc.).

I feel like there's a fairly simple way to do this, but I'm not getting there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will be helpful to get expected result.

```
DECLARE @A TABLE
(
        x INT,
        y VARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT INTO @A (y) SELECT ('aaa') UNION SELECT('bbb') UNION SELECT('ccc')

DECLARE @B TABLE
(
        x INT
)
INSERT INTO @B (X) SELECT (1) UNION SELECT (2)


UPDATE A SET x = B.x FROm 
     (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY y) AS RoW1 FROM @A) AS A
     INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x) AS RoW1 FROM @B) AS B 
     ON A.RoW1 = B.RoW1

SELECT * FROm @A
```

Comment: @GerethD, you forgot the other part of you = in the join, I fixed it for you though

Answer (score -1):

This worked

```
DECLARE @A TABLE
(
        x INT,
        y NVARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO @A (y) VALUES ('aaa'), ('bbb'), ('ccc')

DECLARE @B TABLE
(
        x INT
)
INSERT INTO @B (X) values (1), (2)

Select * into #X from @B
DECLARE @Val1 INT
WHILE 0 < (Select COUNT(*) from #X)
  BEGIN
  SET ROWCOUNT 1
  Select @Val1 = MIN(x) from #X
  UPDATE @A set x = @Val1 where y = (Select MIN(y) from @A where x is null)
  Delete #X where x = @Val1
  if 0 = (Select Count(*) from @A where x is null)
     break

  END
SET ROWCOUNT 0
Select * from @A
```

Its probably not elegant, but it works

Comment: Thanks. Inventive. :-) Sorry, but it didn't occur to me to say "without changing `@B`" in the question; I'll add that now.

Comment: I've changed it, but I think the other answer is better

Comment: Not sure why somebody would downvote it. It answered the question, and I didn't say that it is the perfect code. Some people just like to downvote

Comment: This is needless use of a loop, and while the performance on a table of 3 rows and a table of 2 rows may be acceptable, this will not scale at all well. SQL is a set based language and it is very rare that any solution that involves a loop will be the most efficient.

Comment: The downvote is because the answer is not useful due to the fact that it promotes bad habits, rather than it gives an incorrect solution. Just because it solves the problem it does not mean it is useful, in the same way that if someone asked you for directions from Pretoria to Durban, and you sent them via Capetown, the end result is the same, they have ended up in Durban, but you have taken them significantly out of their way, and I would deem those directions not useful.